# Azure Geo-Redundant for CM, CD, and Analytics

Tags: paas, infrastructure

Is anyone aware of documentation or support for running Sitecore 9.0.2 in Azure PaaS in a Geo-Redundant way for all services.

I know I could put CD in two Regions with publishing targets but not sure about CM and all the analytics App Services and database.  Has anyone done this?  Is this documented anywhere?

Thanks,
Andrew